# Probability 5 Legitimate Requests before 4 Fake.

Tags: probability

If the probability of receiving a legitimate request is 2/3, and the probability of receiving a fake request is 1/3, what is the probability that you will receive 5 legitimate requests before 4 fake ones.

I've been struggling with how to set this up. I tried several things. Including calculating if 5 of the first 8 are legit (8choose5)*(2/3)^5*(1/3)^3, but that doesn't seem like it's the correct answer, since it ignores the 9th request.

I also tried (2/3)^5 / [(1/3)^4+(2/3)^5] = 32/35, but that seemed way too high to be correct. Any help would be appreciated. The limitation that it's before 4 fake requests occur is the part that's confusing me the most.

Comment: Do you mean 5 consecutive legitimate requests? Or just 5 legitimate requests?

Comment: Just 5 legitimate requests.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the desired event of receiving 5 legitimate requests before 4 fake ones is equivalent to the event that the fourth fake request occurs on or after the ninth request.  So if $X \sim \operatorname{NegBinomial}(r,p)$ is a negative binomial random variable that counts the total number of trials needed to obtain the $r^{\rm th}$ failure where $p$ is the individual probability of failure of a single trial, then $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{x-1}{x-r} (1-p)^{x-r} p^r, \quad x = r, r+1, r+2, \ldots.$$  Hence $r = 4$, $p = 1/3$, and we want $\Pr[X \ge 9] = 1 - \Pr[4 \le X \le 8].$

Comment: So to calculate that I would evaluate Pr[X=x] for x = 4,5,6,7,8. Is that right? Something like this? http://i.imgur.com/Tt229yZ.gif

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.